# Using arrays in dictionaries

Tags: swift

Ok, so my first question wasn't great, but now I know to use dictionaries. And I have another question. How can I create a dictionary whose value is an array? I have this so far:

```
var teamScores = [Int: [Int]]()
teamScores[1] = [1,3,4]
teamScores[2] = [5,6,2]
```

but I can't seem to figure out how to add a value to the array for `teamScore[1]` using `.append`. I think the problem is how I reference it: `teamScores[1].append(6)`. Any tips? Thanks!

Original question: Sorry if the title isn't super accurate, I'm not totally sure how to phrase this. So a simplified version of what I have:

```
var Team1 = 3
var Team2 = 4
```

I want to use a for loop and each time I go through the loop I want to reference a different one of the variables like this:

```
for i in 1...2 {
    Team\(i) += 1
}
```

This would work if it was a string, but how do I get it to for the variable name? And in the end, I want it to work with many more variables so using an if statement won't work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use an array, not separate variables.

Comment: It's impossible to assemble variable names at runtime. Variable names are evaluated at **compile** time.

Comment: And it is Swift naming convention to name your variables starting with a lowercase letter.

Answer (score 0):

As [rmaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1226963/rmaddy) suggested you could do the following:

```
var teams = [team1, team2]
for i in 0 ..< teams.count {
    teams[i] += 1
}
```

Comment: Thats wrong you can't mutate a constant. Btw you should iterate the array indices.

Comment: thanks I updated my answer.

Comment: Or `for i in teams.indices { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a dictionary, this way your team ids don't have to be sequential

```
var teamScores = [Int: Int]() // id maps to score

teamScores[1] = 3
teamScores[2] = 4

for i in 1...2 {
   teamScores[i, default: 0] += 1
}
```